# Having trouble importing "google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;"?

Tags: android-youtube-api

I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword

to retreive youtube videos based on keyword using YouTubeData API

This section is giving me the error:
`"Error:(117, 43) error: cannot find symbol variable auth"`

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            })
                    .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample")
                    .build();
```

I think that this class is not being imported

```
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
```

I've searched the internet for someone else having this problem but the question was never answered....can someone please help me?

Answer (score 36):

These two defines can be found in the youtube example:
[Auth.java file from example](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java)

Are you can just replace the Builder string as follows:

```
new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer()
```

This will do  the trick, same as finding the defines.

Hopes this helps, 
BR, 
Adrian.

Comment: Isn't this library from Google? Why on earth does it support Jackson and not Gson?