# import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;

Tags: java, eclipse, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I am trying to do the youtube example [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download#examples) about how to download captions using JAVA.  I was able to import all the libraries that they used except one,  com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth.  I don't konw where to find this libary to import.  This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065065/having-trouble-importing-google-api-services-samples-youtube-cmdline-auth) but im not sure how the given answer helps.

the two lines that need this import are

```
 Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "captions");

youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-captions-sample").build();
```

Comment: As the question you linked to explained, the file you are looking for is at https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java

Answer (score -1):

The library you are looking for is here: https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client

The [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gdata/core) dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```