# what is jar file contains com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth and com.google.common.collect.Lists

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

i tried code youtube api example here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list#examples
but i can import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth and com.google.common.collect.Lists.
i imported all jar file from here: developers.google. com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3
but i get error like that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7OJi.png)

Answer (score 1):

See thie SO entry [Having trouble importing "google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065065/having-trouble-importing-google-api-services-samples-youtube-cmdline-auth)

The class that you're looking for is probably not part of the standard API. However you can build the JAR from the Github from here

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java